# slf4j double lined output

Tags: java, slf4j

I've started using slf4j along with thrift. What I've managed to do is to print single line logs, just like this:

```
[main] INFO FinanceServiceHandler - BEGIN getUserOutcomes
[main] INFO FinanceServiceHandler - found 690 records
[main] INFO FinanceServiceHandler - returned 690 results
[main] INFO FinanceServiceHandler - END getUserOutcomes
```

Corresponding code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FinanceServiceHandler");
    logger.info("BEGIN getUserOutcomes");
    logger.info("found {} records", outcomes.size());
    logger.info("returned {} results", result.size());
    logger.info("END getUserOutcomes");
```

I'm trying to find the way to print double lined logs, just like described [here](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/5/Hello-World-Example-of-Simple-Logging-Facade-for-Java-or-SLF4J) (*6. Console Output*):

[image: slf4j multiline logs]
<sub>(source: [srccodes.com](http://cdn.srccodes.com/c/072012/5/3.png))</sub>

Additionally, when I start my application, Hibernate starts with similar double-line logs:

```
mar 28, 2013 3:12:01 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
mar 28, 2013 3:12:01 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.10.Final}
mar 28, 2013 3:12:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
mar 28, 2013 3:12:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
mar 28, 2013 3:12:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
mar 28, 2013 3:12:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
mar 28, 2013 3:12:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
```

What can I do to make slf4j print double lines with datetime info?

Comment: What logging framework adapter are you using? And you need to configure it there (it's called Pattern in both log4j and logback). A word of advice: if you do this, your log entries will be more difficult to process by any automated process (or even a grep), so I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: @Augusto omg, I don't know what you're talking about. I'm developing [apache thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) service and it has a dependency on [slf4j](http://slf4j.org/). I just added two imports and single lines for logging, nothing more. log4j is different than slf4j.

Comment: tkoomzaaskz, wellcome to java logging hell :). SLF4J stands for Simple Logging **Façade** for Java, the important bit in the name is Façade, as SLF4J provides bridge APIs for all logging frameworks, and then channels them to another framework. Maybe this [bit of the documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) helps you understand this a bit better.